# Is there a smart function to import dynamic components automatically?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

How can I dynamically import dynamic components? I found a few examples, but they seem like a workaround. I couldn't find a clear explanation for that.

I import them one by one like that:

```
Vue.component('account', () => import('../components/Account')
Vue.component('settings', () => import('../components/Settings')
// etc… one for each component
```

and my main component is like that:

```
<component :is="componentName" :data="myData"/>

data: () => ({
  componentName: 'account'
})
```

Is there a way to make a smart method for the first code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://itnext.io/vue-js-app-performance-optimization-part-1-introduction-to-performance-optimization-and-lazy-29e4ff101019).

I need dynamic imports on Webpack.

https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

Answer (score 1):

Try this, adapted from [the Laravel source](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/js/app.js):

```
// replace './' with the relative path to your components
const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], () => import(files(key))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! The component name comes from backend on my application, so I modified the code a bit (removed the files variable and map function) and it worked. This way I only import the required file, not scanning the whole folder and import all of them.

Comment: The only thing, if I create an object const to define paths of components and get this  string type path from the object, it says module could not find

    Vue.component(this.component, () => import(componentFilePath + this.component));

componentFilePath is 100% string. If I manually type the path, it works. Do you know why it happens?